# Setting exact value in X and Y Axes in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[new chart][1][chart][2]

I have this chart in which I want to set the maximum value to the highest value of the data, here it should be 42, but it rounds up the number so it goes to 45, how can I makethe max value exact instead of going in steps?

````
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'scatter',
                data: {
                  datasets: [{
                    label: 'Tiempo-Hole',
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    data: storage,
                    showLine: true,
                  },            
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            ticks: {
                                suggestedMin: 0,  
                                suggestedMax: yPoints[length] ,
                                beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            ticks: {
                                suggestedMin: 0,    
                                suggestedMax: xPoints[xLength] ,
                                beginAtZero: true   
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Altn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k8xe.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use `min` and `max` options, instead of `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` which are useful for extending the range of the axis but maintaining the auto fit behaviour.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const data = [{x:0, y:10}, {x:1, y:20}, {x:2, y:30}, {x:3, y:53}, {x:4, y:40}, {x:5, y:21}, {x:6, y:10}];
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'scatter',
   data: {
     datasets: [{
        label: 'Tiempo-Hole',
        borderColor: 'red',
        fill: false,
        pointRadius: 0,
        data,
        showLine: true,
        clip: 10
     }],
   },
   options: {    
     scales: {
       yAxes: [{
         display: true,
         ticks: {
           min: 0,  
           max: data.reduce(function (max, item) {
             return ( max > item.y ? max : item.y);
           }),
           stepSize: data.reduce(function (max, item) {
             return ( max > item.y ? max : item.y);
           }) / 10,
           callback: (value) => Math.trunc(value),
           beginAtZero: true
         }
       }],
       xAxes: [{
         display: true,
         ticks: {
           min: 0,    
           max: data.reduce(function (max, item) {
             return ( max > item.x ? max : item.x);
           }),
           beginAtZero: true   
         }
       }]
     }
   }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: it kind of works, but it stops on 40, like it doesnt get the last x value which is 41.6 or something and ends in the prvious which is 39.8

Comment: im gonna upload the new chart image im getting where i included the code you sent only in the x axe, that is where i need it

Comment: I have also a codepen to play on this use case: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/wvmZEqP